# Inequality for line integral

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, line-integrals

Let $F(x)$ be a continuous (not necessarily monotonic) function defined on smooth curve $C$. I am wondering if the following inequality holds for line integrals.

$$|F(a)-F(b)|\leq \int_C ||f(x)||dx\leq \sup_{x\in C}|| f(x)||\cdot L_C$$

where $f(x)=\nabla F(x)$ is the gradient of $F(x)$,  $L_C$ is the length of the curve $C$ and $||\cdot||$ is some norm (e.g., $\ell_2$ norm). We also assume that $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in C}|| f(x)||$ is bounded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $F : {\bf R}^n\rightarrow {\bf R}$ and any curve
$c:[0,1]\rightarrow {\bf R}^n,\ t\mapsto (x_1(t),\cdots, x_n(t))$
where $c(0)=p,\ c(1)=q$. Then consider a function $ g(t):= (F\circ
c)(t)$ Here $\circ$ means composite : $ (F\circ c)(t) = F(c(t))$.
That is $g : [0,1] \rightarrow {\bf R}$. So recall the fundamental
theorem in calculus. We will apply to $g$ : $$ g(1)-g(0)= \int_0^1
g'(t) dt\ \ast $$

Here $g$ is composite function. So we compute at details. First by change rule, $$
 g'(t) =\sum_{k=1}^n
 \frac{\partial }{\partial x^k} F  \frac{d}{dt} x_k (t) $$

Usually we denote it : $$ g'(t) = dF(c'(t)) = \nabla F\cdot c'(t)
$$  In the first $dF$ is $1\times n$-matrix and in the second, the
gradient $\nabla F$ is a vector. In fact matrix multiplication is
equal to inner product in this case.

And $$ F(q)-F(p)= g(1)-g(0)= \int_0^1 g'(t)dt = \int_0^1 \nabla
F\cdot c'(t)
 dt $$ so that $$| F(q)-F(p)| \leq \int_0^1 |\nabla F| |c'(t)| dt
 \leq {\rm sup} |\nabla F|  \cdot {\rm length} (c)$$

Here we used $|\int k(t) dt|\leq \int|k(t)|dt$, $
|v\cdot w|\leq |v||w|$ and $\int_0^1 |c'(t)|dt = {\rm
length} (c)$

Comment: Thanks for the help @Hee Kwon Lee. However, I am not quite familiar with the technique you used here. You redefine all the variables in terms of $t$, so the curve $C$ and $F$ are the function of $t$. Am I right? Does inequality hold for $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$ (not just $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: Also, what does the symbol $\circ$ mean?

Comment: I add more explanations

Comment: Thanks so much @Hee Kwon Lee! The explanations are very clear and detailed!

Comment: A quick question: it seems that you didn't prove the first inequality--$|F(a)-F(b)|\leq \int_C ||f(x)||dx$. Do we have $\int_0^1 |c'(t)|dt=\int_C dx$? If so, it will be trivial to prove it based on your solution.

Comment: I try to answer my question. As $||\nabla F||$ is a scalar function, we have $\int_0^1||\nabla F|| |c'(t)|dt = \int_C||\nabla F|| dx$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you're right. $\int_0^1 f(t)|c'(t)| dt =\int_C f dx$ for any scalar function along a curve $c$.