# complex inequality (solution verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be entire, $|f(z)|\leq 3|z|^4+1$ prove $f$ is a polynomial with deggre $\leq 4$

**Solution:**

$f^{(4)}(z_0)=\frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_c\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^5}dz$,  $\Rightarrow$  $|f^{(4)}(z_0)|\leq \frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_c |\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^5}|dz \leq \frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_c \frac{|f(z)|}{|(z-z_0)^5|}dz \leq$ $$\leq \frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{|f(z_0+re^{it})ire^{it}|}{|(re^{it})^5|}dt \leq \frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(3(|z_0|+r)^4+1)r}{r^5}dt \leq  \frac{4!}{2\pi i} 2\pi\frac{(3(|z_0|+r)^4+1)}{r^4}$$

that means $f^{(4)}(z)$ is bounded so from Liouville's theorem its constant and therefore $f$ is a polynomial with deggre $\leq 4$

**Is my solution correct ?**

Comment: Math.se is a Q&A site...

Comment: That means I can't ask if my solution is correct or not ?

Comment: I don't write it maybe I should(I will edit it now), but I think its implied

Comment: Is this different from your previous question  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4143191/42969 ?

Comment: I just need a yes or no answer.

Comment: @MartinR Can we have these merged in a similar way to the merger of yesterday's duplicates?

Comment: @MarkViola: Only moderators can merge threads. As I understand it, that is not often done, and only if *both* threads have good answers. That is not the case here. – However, since you voted this question as a duplicate of an older one, it would have been better (IMO) to answer the older question.

Comment: @MartinR I had not seen the older question existed until after I posted this solution and then saw your comment.  This happened yesterday and I was admonished to not post on both pages.   So, I could delete my answer herein and post it on the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct.   There are a few minor errata.  Note that

$$f^{(4)}(z)=\frac{4!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^5}\,dw$$

where $C$ is a rectifiable closed contour that encloses the point $z$.

We may choose $C$ to be the circular contour $|w-z|=r$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
|f^{(4)}(z)|&=\left|\frac{4!}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^5}\,dw\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{4!}{2\pi \color{red}{\underbrace{|i|}_{=1}}}\left|\int_0^{2\pi } \frac{|f(z+re^{i\phi})|}{|r|^5}|\color{red}{\underbrace{ire^{i\phi}}_{=r}}|\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&\le\frac{4!}{r^4}\max_{\phi}|f(z+re^{i\phi})|\\\\
&\le \frac{4!(3\max_{\phi}(|z+re^{i\phi}|^4)+1)}{r^4}\\\\
&=\frac{4!(3(r+|z|)^4+1)}{r^4}
\end{align}$$

Letting $r\to \infty$ shows that

$$|f^{(4)}(z)|\le 72$$

whereby appealing to Liousville's Theorem implies that $f^{(4)}(z)$ is constant from which we conclude that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of order $4$.